# How to get rid of ORA-28002 message the password will expire within 6 days?

Tags: oracle, security

I have a user getting an ORA-28002 indicating that the password will expire within six days.  I ran the following:

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
```

But when I try to log in as the user, the message is still there. Executing this:

```
select * from dba_profiles where RESOURCE_NAME LIKE 'PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME';
```

shows that the values was really changed to UNLIMITED.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The password has been marked as 'EXPIRED' or marked with an 'EXPIRY_DATE' in dba_users. You will have to change it. You can set it back to the same password. The easy way would be setting the password "by values". This usually bypasses history checking.

```
12:28:33 SQL> select * from dba_users where username = 'MYUSER1';

USERNAME                          USER_ID PASSWORD
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
ACCOUNT_STATUS                   LOCK_DATE          EXPIRY_DATE
-------------------------------- ------------------ ------------------
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE             TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE           CREATED
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------
PROFILE                        INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP
------------------------------ ------------------------------
EXTERNAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYUSER1                               338 66856982BE5CD23F
OPEN
USERS                          TEMP                           17-JAN-11
DEFAULT                        DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP



Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
12:28:43 SQL> alter user myuser1 password expire;

User altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:29:11 SQL> select * from dba_users where username = 'MYUSER1';

USERNAME                          USER_ID PASSWORD
------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
ACCOUNT_STATUS                   LOCK_DATE          EXPIRY_DATE
-------------------------------- ------------------ ------------------
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE             TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE           CREATED
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------
PROFILE                        INITIAL_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP
------------------------------ ------------------------------
EXTERNAL_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MYUSER1                               338 66856982BE5CD23F
EXPIRED                                             17-JAN-11
USERS                          TEMP                           17-JAN-11
DEFAULT                        DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP



Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
12:29:14 SQL>
```

The format of this is "alter user USER identified by values 'hash from dba_users.password';"

```
[TEST] C:\>sqlplus system

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mon Jan 17 12:18:16 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

new: showmode BOTH
12:18:17 SQL> prompt end of LOGIN.SQL
end of LOGIN.SQL
12:18:17 SQL> create user myuser1 identified by mypassword1;

User created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:18:21 SQL> grant connect, resource to myuser1;

Grant succeeded.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:18:30 SQL> connect myuser1/mypassword1
Connected.
12:18:39 SQL> connect system
Enter password:
Connected.
12:18:51 SQL> alter user myuser1 password expire;

User altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
12:19:05 SQL> connect myuser1/mypassword1
ERROR:
ORA-28001: the password has expired


Changing password for myuser1
New password:
Retype new password:
Password changed
Connected.
12:19:16 SQL> connect myuser1/mypassword1
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
12:19:21 SQL> connect system
Enter password:
Connected.
12:19:34 SQL> alter user myuser1 identified by mypassword1;

User altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:19:49 SQL> alter user myuser1 identified by mypassword1 password expire;

User altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:20:26 SQL> select username, password from dba_users where username = 'MYUSER1';

USERNAME                       PASSWORD
------------------------------ ------------------------------
MYUSER1                        66856982BE5CD23F

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:20:36 SQL> alter user myuser1 identified by values '66856982BE5CD23F' ;

User altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
12:21:01 SQL> connect myuser1/mypassword1
Connected.
12:21:13 SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Answer (score 18):

Please find the below three queries and run these queries from system database.

```
// For seeing full user details
SELECT profile FROM dba_users WHERE username = 'SYSTEM';

// This query is used to change the password life time to unlimited
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED; 

// This query is used to change the default password.
alter user SYSTEM identified by "system";
```

Comment: Pretty easy and well explained.

Answer (score 5):

A coworker using Toad saw the account indicated as looked in the Schema Browsers under Users.

We succeeded  by right clicking **unlock user**.
In the Alter user dialog we reentered the old password and unchecked the Password is locked checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but for those using Oracle SQL Developer follow these step:

- Use another user to log into any database connection you have, you
  can use the default "system" or "sys" username with whatever password you got
  there.
- Open connection tree and find the "Other Users" node and open that
  like so :

[image]

- Find your username in the child notes under "Other Users" and right
  click to edit user like so:

[image]

- Type in your new password and Un-check password expired, then apply.
  Right click edit user again to see if the settings were changed if
  you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the password again for the new limit to take effect.

Comment: I want to keep the same password

Comment: The answer from REW meets this additional requirement assuming you do not have a profile preventing password re-use.  If you are on 11g or later the password hash is not in dba_users, so you will need to get it from sys.user$.  See http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/08/the-password-is-not-longer-displayed-in-dba_userspassword.html

Answer (score 2):

You should alter the user account. First connect to your `sys` account and from there you can perform below mentioned step:

```
alter user practice identified by password;
```

this will resolve your issue...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are getting this error, very simple fix:
connect to database. suppose sample and sample is your oracle user id and password.

ashutosh@LINUX:/oracle/path#sqlplus sample/sample

ERROR:
ORA-28002: the password will expire within 7 days

Last Successful login time: Tue Jan 10 2023 23:51:33 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> password

Changing password for SAMPLE

Old password:

New password:

Retype new password:

Password changed

SQL>

your password will be change.